# For which $\alpha > \kappa$ is "X has cardinality $\kappa$" absolute in $L_\alpha$?

Tags: set-theory

This is a much more general question than a question that is relevant while doing exercises 13.7 and 13.8 in Jech, namely "Is countability absolute in $L_\kappa$" for $\kappa$ regular? Countability is upward absolute since it is $\Sigma_1$, but I don't see the proof of the other direction. Any help just on this question would be appreciated, but it makes me wonder about the title question.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but there is no clean answer. One usually addresses this is terms of fine structure. The key concept is "projectum."

Comment: The other direction is false, of course. Note that for any cardinal $\kappa$ there is some $\alpha<\omega_1$ such that $L_\alpha\prec L_\kappa$ (by Skolem-Lowenheim, Mostowski, and condensation); so for $\kappa=\omega_2$ it means that this $L_\alpha$ thinks that some countable ordinal is $\omega_1$.

Comment: But Asaf, that $\alpha$ wouldn't be regular right?

Comment: Well, regular in $V$ or in $L$? :-)

Comment: In V - I think the reverse ought to be true since Jech at least seems to be using it, at least for $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$